# trying to get current user using session flask, but variable returns an empty list

Tags: python, mysql, flask, session, mysql-python

Im creating an event manager web app.. and right now I'm trying to query the events that the current user is in.

```
@classmethod
    def getevent(cls, id):
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()

        sql = f"SELECT name, description FROM event Where p_id = {id} Order by id"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        return result
```

this is the function that gets the event name and description where Participant ID (p_id) is equal to the current user (session['userID']

```
@routes.route("/listofevents", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def Levents():
    id = session['userID']
    events = models.Event.getevent(id)
    
    print(id)
    print(events)
    return render_template("index_ListofEvents.html", events = events)
```

the route. This works fine but nothing shows up in the webpage.. when i try to print the the events it returns an empty list []

Can anybody help me please. What am I missing?

EDIT:
when I run the query in phpmyadmin it works but I need to replace {id} in string format e.g. '2020-6969' but when I print session it just returns int
2020-6969

Comment: The query found no matches, so it returned an empty list.

Comment: Did you try running that exact query in a database client?

Comment: I did and it found the events.

Comment: As a debugging step, print the `sql` string to make absolutely sure it has what you expect.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Did the `print(id)` print out correct ?

Comment: @hungtran273 yes, print id prints out correct..

Comment: Try again with `p_id = '{id}'`

Comment: If you added single quotes around `id` in phpmyadmin, then you did _not_ run the same query that the code uses.  The code is looking for that value as an integer, which was not found.

Comment: `where p_id = 2020-6969` is interpreted as `where p_id = -4949`, because `2020-6969` is an integer expression meaning "2020 minus 6969".